# strlen on array returns 5 in php

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

From the docs -

```
int strlen ( string $string )
```

it takes string as a parameter, now when I am doing this-

```
$a = array('tex','ben');
echo strlen($a);
```

Output -
`5`

However I was expecting, two type of output-

1. If it is an array, php might convert it into string so the array will become-

   `'texben'` so it may output - `6`
2. If 1st one is not it will convert it something like this -

   `"array('tex','ben')"` so the expected output should be - `18` (count of all items)

But every time it output- `5`

My consideration from the output is `5` from `array` word count but I am not sure. If it is the case how PHP is doing this ?(means counting 5)

Comment: Together with this code you should be getting an "array conversion to string" warning message. When you get such a warning you are almost always doing something you should not be.

Comment: You need to configure your development box to display all error messages: [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/I3KO1).

Comment: @Jon I executed it here ..but no warnings as u mentioned??  http://codepad.org/4D9pC447

Comment: @Trialcoder - See [updated codepad](http://codepad.org/vgzV1Hcc).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario ohh..wow really dont know abt this ..thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function casts the input as a string, and so arrays become `Array`, which is why you get a count of 5.

It's the same as doing:

```
$a = array('tex','ben');

echo (string)$a; // Array
var_dump((string)$a); // string(5) "Array"
```

This is the behavior prior to PHP 5.3. However in PHP 5.3 and above, `strlen()` will return `NULL` for arrays.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

> strlen() returns NULL when executed on arrays, and an E_WARNING level error is emitted.
>
> Prior [to 5.3.0] versions treated arrays as the string Array, thus returning a string length of 5 and emitting an E_NOTICE level error.

Comment: String is an array of characters. It is strange that strlen() return null for all arrays but array of char-s. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$a = array('tex','ben');
$lengths = array_map('strlen',$a);
```

to get an array of individual lengths, or

```
$a = array('tex','ben');
$totalLength = array_sum(array_map('strlen',$a));
```

to get the total of all lengths

Comment: Why complicate things when: `strlen(implode($a))` will work fine?

Comment: Well if the OP wants an array of individual string lengths, the first solution isn't complicating things; the second is a natural extension from that, though I'll conceded it is more complicated than implode() and strlen()

Comment: @MarkBaker +1 for two new methods..i will investigate more abt these two soon :)

Comment: @MarkBaker It depends on what OP wants. If only requirement is to count characters in array with this structure I'd go with implode. Personally I hate passing closures as strings (i.e. passing names of pre-defined functions) it makes debugging nightmare in large projects.

Comment: @PLB - though using a closure as the first argument simply to do the strlen is even more ugly

Comment: I just tried a comparison of the 2 methods on an array of 40k elements. `strlen(implode($a))` was about 12 times faster than `array_sum(array_map('strlen',$a))` so definitely better to use the `strlen(implode())` method!

Answer (score 2):

The array is implicitly converted to a string. In PHP this yields the output `Array`, which has 5 letters as `strlen()` told you.

You can easily verify this, by running this code:

```
$a = array('tex','ben');
echo $a;
```